# Linux: Can I get the wicd daemon to disconnect my wireless network from the command line?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wicd

I'm thrilled using [wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/) to connect to wireless networks.  But when I suspend my laptop using the special keys, I just want to disconnect from wireless without having to use any kind of GUI or curses user interface.  It says in the documentation that wicd works by sending DBUS messages, so presumably it's possible to write a command that talks to the daemon directly.  But I can't figure out how.

Does anybody know by means of what shell command I can tell the wicd daemon to disconnect me from my wireless network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wound up just using

```
sudo ifdown --force wlan0
```

and I follow up by using `modprobe` to unload the drivers.  It turns out that `wicd` copes with this brutality just fine, and on resume from suspend, I reload the drivers, run `wicd-curses`, and it graciously connects me to my preferred network.

I love `wicd`!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had much luck with [wicd-cli](http://packages.debian.org/sid/wicd-cli), but this does seem to work:

```
wicd-cli -yx
```

See 'wicd-cli --help' for some very sparse documentation.